# How to call function in select statement and calculate total?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following tables like below :

```
Employees : EmployeeId, EmpName , DepartmentId

Transaction: TransactionId, EmployeeId
```

I have a query which returns list of Employees:

```
select * from Employees e
inner join Department d on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
--some other joins
where d.DepartmentId in (@departmentIds)
--other filters
```

I have a "Scalar-Valued" function called "`GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId`" which calculates employee commission for each transaction and returns "Commission" for that particular transaction.

Now I want to do left join with transaction table and call "`GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId`" on each transaction and get "Total Commission" in final result like below:

Final Result set :

```
EmployeeId  EmpName   DepartmentId   Total Commission
1           John      100             1000
2           Frieda    200             2000
```

But I am a little confused with calling the function and then passing multiple transaction ids for each employee and calculating total commission.

Can someone please help me with this?

The function looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId]
(
    @transactionId INT
)
RETURNS Decimal(18,0)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Commission DECIMAL;
  -----Logic to calculate commission---------
  RETURN @Commission;
End
```

Comment: Your question *implies* that your scalar function expects a table type parameter. If so, then you can't pass the dataset to it unless you define a variable of the correct type, `INSERT` the data into said variable, and then pass it to your function. If this is the case, seems like what you should *really* be doing is designing an **inline** table value function.

Comment: @Larnu I updated my question to include the function definition as well. Could you suggest me now what should I do?

Comment: @DaleK I updated my question to include the function definition as well. Now could you suggest me something please?

Comment: If you don't want to change your function as suggested by @Larnu (which is the best way) then you have to call you function once per transaction and group/sum the result.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry but I didnt understood the overall idea suggested by Larnu. Is is possible to provide a sample answer with the rough idea for me to begin with please?

Comment: *RETURNS Decimal(18,0)* - so that's actually a  `bigint` then?

Comment: @Stu Yes actually its a big number with decimal points

Comment: (18,0) means 0 digits after the decimal point. `declare @x decimal(18,0)=12345.6789; print @x` = `12346`

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow its a big subject, really one you need to education yourself on, the official docs are always a good place to start e.g. [Inline Table Valued Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-creating-an-inline-table-valued-function) and [Using Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Stu Oh sorry. Actually its 2 digits after the decimal.I forgot to include (18,2). Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @DaleK IF I create a inline table value function but how do I pass multiple transaction id and then get a final "Total Commission" in my final result set because I want to only consider Transaction Id of employees based on my filter

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow actually take a step back, why pass in a transaction id or a list of them? Why not just pass in the EmployeeId?

Comment: @DaleK Because GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId inside the function is working with TransactionId that's why.

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow all the suggestions for improvements involve writing a new function. Otherwise you already have my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the commission over multiple transactions using the function you have created, you have to `sum` the result of the function over all relevant transactions then group your data to get the required columns.

```
select e.EmployeeId, e.EmpName, d.DepartmentId
    , sum(dbo.GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId(t.id)) Commission
from Employees e
inner join Department d on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
left join [Transaction] t on t.EmployeeId = e.Id
where d.DepartmentId in (@departmentIds)
group by e.EmployeeId, e.EmpName, d.DepartmentId;
```

However as pointed out in the comments a more performant approach would be an Inline Table Valued Function which takes in the EmployeeId rather than a TransactionId.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Just a small thing that I also have a filter to search for commission like user can enter Min and Max commission value and then the data will be filtered accordingly. This filter will be part of having clause right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you're joining to the transaction table but how about using outer apply.

```
SELECT e.Id AS EmployeeId, e.EmpName, e.DepartmentId, tx.TotalCommission
FROM Employees e 
    INNER JOIN Department d ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id 
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT [dbo].[GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId](t.TransactionId) AS TotalComission 
        FROM Transactions t WHERE t.EmployeeId = e.Id) tx
```